# GCC #pragma message ignored

Tags: c++, c, gcc, pragma

I am trying to [display a compile-time message in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas), via

```
#pragma message "hello world"
```

But when I compile with `-Wall` it gives the warning

```
warning: ignoring #pragma message
```

I'm using GCC 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

Why isn't it displaying the message? How can I make it display the message?

Comment: That documentation is for GCC 4.8.0.  You're using 4.2.1.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suspected that was the answer, but I was having trouble finding the old documentation. I feel it was a legitimate question, considering it wasn't trivial to find, and OSX ships with an older version of GCC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *was* trivial to find.  I googled "gcc 4.2.1 documentation" and it was the first hit (or close enough).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read the [correct documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas), you'll find that `#pragma message` isn't supported in GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: It is documented starting with [version 4.4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas). It is not documented in [version 4.3.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)